# Creating schematic view of line feature in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, schematics

I have a line feature (polyline with curves) in ArcGIS Desktop, and I want to create a linear representation (straight line) of the feature, furthermore I want to be able to locate events in the linear representation. This is something like I would like:

[image]

Making some research I found something similar called "column view" unlucky my PC rebooted an does not saved the history of the browser... so I lost the document. (I have been searching for it again, but I have not been able to find it)

In the petroleum industry they call it "Alignment Sheet", is a representation of the objects that are located over a route but in a straight line. But keep in mind that is not linear referencing. Think in this way: you have a road, with its events, it is a curve, the idea is to straight it and view the event over that line.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about Schematics? Do you have the Schematics extension installed and licensed? Have a look at that.

Comment: yes, i do have the schematic extension

Comment: If ArcGIS Schematics does not provide a solution be sure to come back and edit your question with what you have tried and where it may not be meeting your requirements.  Try and keep your question as focussed as possible.

Comment: I don't think what you want is schematics.  You should investigate the linear referencing tools in ArcGIS.

Comment: @Fezter, I already check the linear referencing tools, but they do not provide something  that the one I was looking for.

Comment: @XtianGIS Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: @Wilson not yet, is still bugging my mind